# Analyse huge amount of blockchain data

Tags: data-science, blockchain, data-analysis, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I am trying to go over all transactions data from every block on the bitcoin blockchain from the previous 4 years. With almost 2k transaction per block, it will take a lot of queries per block.
I have a full node running locally and I tried two ways:

Python with RPC: This is very slow and keeps losing connection after some time (httpx.ReadTimeout)

Python with os.popen commands: Doesn't have the connection problem, but still very slow.

Would there be any other way? Any recommendation on how to analyze bulk data from the blockchain? The methods listed above are unfeasible given the time it would take.

EDIT: The problem isn't memory, but the time the bitcoin node takes to answer the queries.

Comment: Could you precise what your analysis would consist in? If it is quite simple, then powering off your full node and proceeding your analysis on [transactions](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/transactions.html) in each [block](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/block_chain.html) thanks to reading [the binary `.blk` files](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/blkdat) would be far more faster than the method you proposed. I usually proceed this way to make statistics on the whole Bitcoin blockchain.

Comment: Hi, it is very simple, but I need to be able to find the transactions on the block chain using the txid. Is is possible to do using only the blk files?

Comment: The `.blk` files are the Bitcoin blockchain (cf above binary documentation of these files). There is *everything* in it, you just have to work a bit on it to extract what you are looking for. Note that saying *it is very simple* doesn't state what you are looking for, so it doesn't help people willing to help you.

Comment: For all transactions in each block I am trying to get the time between received input vs spent input. For example, if address XYZ created a transaction in block 500, I want the time between block 500 and the block when the input for the transaction was received in address XYZ.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there are differents ways to fetch bitcoin blockchain data:

- Network level using [P2P messages](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/p2p_networking.html#getblocks) (this method doesn't require to setup a node)
- Parsing `.blk` files which are synchronized by your node
- Querying the application interface `RPC`

P2P messages and `.blk` files are raw encoded, so you will need to decode blocks and transactions.

The RPC interface abstract the raw decoding but it's slower (because it decodes).

We wrote a paper with Matthieu Latapy to give instructions about collecting the whole Bitcoin blockchain and indexing in order to make parsing efficient.

- [Step-by-step procedure](https://ethicnology.github.io/full-bitcoin-blockchain-data-made-easy/scripts/)
- [Full paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.08072)
- [Repository](https://github.com/ethicnology/blockchain-ekstrakto)
- [Website](https://ethicnology.github.io/full-bitcoin-blockchain-data-made-easy/)